# alternative format to PDF format for Android development

Tags: android, pdf, text, webview, android-support-library

I am developing an Android application which only  works with text documents. Currently I'm using PDF format. But the total size of all the documents leads to some 25-30mb, too much for an app. 
The app is required to open the text documents and also allow features like zoom, search, etc. For this we considered a PDF viewing library, but that is simply increasing the size of the app.

We have considered redirecting the PDF's to open in default apps in the phones. But there are some text documents that NEED to be viewed through our own app. But a PDF viewing library isnt the best solution due to already huge size.

my question is : **is there any alternative format to PDF format** to be used in Android application that **allows file compressibility** without loss of quality?

and **does not require a third party library** to open the text documents.

Also , will I be able to zoom in on the text?

Comment: i think epub file u can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any alternative format to PDF format to be used in Android application that allows file compressibility without loss of quality?

HTML.

> does not require a third party library to open the text documents

The `WebView` widget in Android can render HTML.

> will I be able to zoom in on the text?

You as a developer can control the zoom level of the `WebView`, and users may also be able to use pinch-to-zoom gestures, depending on your content and the `WebView` size.

Comment: I tried your solution. it is a plausible solution. but I have some files that are in PDF format and I am converting them to HTML. The problem here is rendering issues. there is a lot of symbols involved and HTML is messing up the formatting. I need PERFECT conversion of PDF to HTML or maybe another solution to this problem. Please help?